# How to map values from a data.table to a data.table (R)

Tags: r, data.table

I have two map/data.tables. One consists of key-values and another one just of some keys. I want to map the values from the first map to the keys of the second. How can this be done?

Here is some example code:

```
map1<-data.table( k=c("A","B"), v=c(2,3) )
map2<-data.table( k2=c("A","B","A","A"))
```

How can I produce a new column v2 in map2 which contains c(2,3,2,2)?

Comment: Have you read through the [Getting Started vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use a data.table join:

```
map1[map2, v, on = c(k = "k2")]
#[1] 2 3 2 2

map2[map1, v2 := v, on = c(k2 = "k")]
#   k2 v2
#1:  A  2
#2:  B  3
#3:  A  2
#4:  A  2
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this using `base R`

```
map2$v2 <- map1$v[match(map2$k2,map1$k)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this. It's not quite as elegant, but I find it more intuitive:

```
map2 = merge(
  x = map2,
  y = map1,
  by.x = 'k2',
  by.y = 'k',
  all.x = T
)

setnames(map2, old = c('v'), new = c('v2')
```